# Get startup position

Tags: c

i need to find the startup position of a script in C. I must check if my script has been launched from /usr/bin or from another directory. I've tried with get_current_directory_name() but it returns the current path where I was browsing when i launched the script, so if I do:
cd /home/myaccount/ && my-script 
it returns /home/myaccount, but what i need is the startup position.

Comment: /bin/bash is not a directory ...

Comment: what script?  and what do you mean by "in C" ?

Comment: The word _script_ is usually used to refer to a program that is interpreted at run time, not pre-compiled binary executables.  It has its roots in scipting an interaction with a shell program (like `/bin/sh`), but has been extended to other interpreted program text.

Comment: Why do you care what directory the "script" is in?

Answer (score 6):

`readlink("/proc/self/exe", buffer, buffer_size)`

This will get you the location of the executable under Linux.  `man 2 readlink`

If you are not using Linux you can try examining `argv[0]` and see if that is the location of the currently running program, but it is entirely possible to run a program with a different `argv[0]` than the path to the program; it could be either the executable name, relative path, or even something that has nothing at all to do with the program being run.

A last effort to determine this could be to search for the program in the `PATH`, and assume that if it is there then that was how it was run.  I wouldn't trust this very much, though.

The best solution is to not write a program that relies on this type of information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `cd /home/myaccount` will change the current directory before `my-script` is launched, which means that `my-script` will not know where it originally was. Maybe you can look at the `OLDPWD` environment variable, but that will not tell you if you switched dir just before you ran `my-script` or a long time before that.

Or maybe I misunderstood you. Maybe you are looking for argv[0]?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
}
```

Comment: I moved my script to /usr/bin, I need to check if the script has been launched from /usr/bin or not

Answer (score 0):

Fabio,

If you run a 'C script' then you have a process which has executed (interpreted or compiled on-the-fly) this .c source code file.

When you will try to identify the 'starting point or origin of the script' you will find the parent process path and name.

There is no way to execute a C script from the position of its source code file - **unless** the parent process is actually compiling the C source code file into an executable file (which can then be stored at any place where the parent process has access).

Hope is clarrifies this issue.

Answer (score -1):

besides argv[0], you can try getcwd() to get the path

Comment: -1 This give the directory of invocation not the one where the executable is located. From the question it seems that the OP had already tried that.